# How to properly upgrade .NET SDK version to update an included package version to resolve downgrade conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, maui, maui-blazor

I just created a MAUI Blazor project (hybrid) in Visual Studio. My SDK is the latest (`7.0.400`) and my VS is also up-to-date (`17.7.3`).

However, the referred packages (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is in interest here) stays at `7.0.0`:

[image]

Now when I try to install `Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI`, it requires `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 7.0.1)` so I receive this error:

> Error NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade:
> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions from 7.0.1 to 7.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> MyProject -> Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI 3.0.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 7.0.10 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components 7.0.10 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 7.0.10 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 7.0.1)
> MyProject -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)

Now from Visual Studio's Nuget UI I cannot install the package directly so I did through the CLI and there is this error:

> error: Error while performing Update for package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions'. Cannot edit items in imported files -
> error:   Item 'PackageReference' for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' in Imported file 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\7.0.92\Sdk\BundledVersions.targets'.

So I just add it directly to my project (`.csproj`):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="7.0.1" />
```

Now after a restore and reload, I can add `Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI` package but every time I build, I get this warning:

> A PackageReference for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' was included in your project. This package is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you do not typically need to reference it from your project. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs

How do I get rid of that annoying message? What is the problem here? Can I fix it or MS forgot to update their SDK references?

I also just noticed that with `(>= 7.0.0)` requirement, shouldn't it be able to resolve with `7.0.1`? Is it actually a Nuget problem?

---

My .NET SDKs:

```
> dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: Apparently it's [a MAUI issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16244)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package in the package manager console using the following command.

[image: PM Console]

```
install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
```

I tried in Maui project and it worked.

Comment: Interesting that the old `Install-Package` command works. I did successfully install it, there's still the annoying warnings when building the project though.